# Flot Tooltip Plugin - Multi Y axis values

Tags: jquery, tooltip, flot

I've been getting on well with the Flot tooltip plugin but I'm struggling to figure out a way to set the content of the tool tip to display several Y axis series values at the same time which are related to one X axis value.

For example:

```
Day: Tue (X axis)
a: 256
b: 247
c: 371
```

Is this possible in the current tooltip or has someone already created this?

Comment: First, show your plot code.  Second, each series can only plot against one y-axis.  When you mouse-over a series, you get's it's corresponding y value from it's y-axis.  How do you map to the other y-axis?  Do you want the value that "overlaps" your series y-value?